# how to get 2 false Boolean and return true as result

Tags: c#, boolean

In math, we have `-1 * -1 = 1`. When 2 negatives multiplies together, we get a positive.

However in C# `bool`, I am not able to find a way to do so.

```
int i = -1
int j = -1

bool bi = i>0
bool bj = j>0

Console.writeLine (bi) 
Console.writeLine (bj)
Console.writeLine (bi && bj)
```

result:

```
false

false

false
```

obviously, the && is the not the right operator.
Which operator allows me to have 2 Boolean when both are false, returning true

i.e.
Console.Writeline (false  false)
result true

Comment: Use `==` - `bi == bj`

Comment: And what should the result be when both are true, or true+false?

Comment: `false` is kind-of `0`, not `-1`. So `0 * 0 = 0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closest to your logic is using negated XOR:

```
! (bi ^ bj);
```

This way you'd get something like:

```
1 * 1 = 1
-1 * 1 = -1
1 * -1 = -1
```

Also you could use simple comparison operator `==`:

```
bi == bj;
```

Comment: Would `==` give the same results?

Comment: @mjwills ... yes it would! :) Updated :)

Comment: I am somewhat mystified how there are so many fancy re-implementations of equality for this question!

Answer (score 4):

> Which operator allows me to have 2 Boolean when both are false,
>   returning true

If you want to check two values are equal (e.g. both are `true` or both are `false`) then `==` (the [equality operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/)) is your best bet.

```
var bob = true == true;
var bob2 = false == false;
```

Both `bob` and `bob2` will be `true`.

This is perfect for your problem since you want to know if **both** numbers are negative *or* **both** numbers are positive (since in either of those scenarios, multiplying them will result in a positive number).

Answer (score -1):

Console.Writeline(bi == false && bj == false) or for short (!bi && !bj)